# Enqueued sound data is not playing using OpenSL on Android

Tags: android, opensl

I am working on a project using OpenSL for Android and I came on a problem.
In this following case, the wave data enqueued will be skipped in rare occasions.

```
SLObjectItf mpSLPlayerObject;
SLPlayItf 　　　mpPlayItf;
SLAndroidSimpleBufferQueueItf mpBufferQueueItf;

(*mpSLPlayerObject)->GetInterface(mpSLPlayerObject, SL_IID_PLAY, &mpPlayItf);
(*mpSLPlayerObject)->GetInterface(mpSLPlayerObject, SL_IID_BUFFERQUEUE, &mpBufferQueueItf);

(*mpPlayItf)->SetPlayState(mpPlayItf, SL_PLAYSTATE_PLAYING);
(*mpBufferQueueItf)->Enqueue(mpBufferQueueItf, pBuffer, bufferSize);
```

The status of mpPlayItf will change to SL_PLAYSTATE_PLAYING and the data is successfully enqueued.
But, the data in mpBufferQueueItf stays permanently and the status of mpPlayItf doesn't change.

But, in the following case

```
SLObjectItf mpSLPlayerObject;
SLPlayItf 　　　mpPlayItf;
SLAndroidSimpleBufferQueueItf mpBufferQueueItf;

(*mpSLPlayerObject)->GetInterface(mpSLPlayerObject, SL_IID_PLAY, &mpPlayItf);
(*mpSLPlayerObject)->GetInterface(mpSLPlayerObject, SL_IID_BUFFERQUEUE, &mpBufferQueueItf);

(*mpBufferQueueItf)->Enqueue(mpBufferQueueItf, pBuffer, bufferSize);
(*mpPlayItf)->SetPlayState(mpPlayItf, SL_PLAYSTATE_PLAYING);
```

When I swapped the two lines for Enqueue and SetPlayState, all wave data will be played flawlessly.

I am facing this problem on the 3 device below.

> Nexus 5X Android 6.0
>   Xperia X Performance Android 7.0
>   Xperia Z4 Android 5.0

There may be more device with the same problem but I have no idea.
Is this a bug or I have to enqueue my data before setting up the play state?
Does anyone face the same problem with me?

Comment: Are you sure to use the same sampling and size in the buffer queue as the pcm buffer queue player ? (e.g. SL_SAMPLINGRATE_44_1 and SL_PCMSAMPLEFORMAT_FIXED_16). Also make sure pBuffer remains valid see my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44949972/cannot-play-pcm-60kb-with-the-androidsimplebufferqueue

Comment: The sampling and size in both buffer queue is the same. Plus, our buffer remains valid too.
We did check with some other device and they plays flawlessly. Only certain device is experiencing this issue so I guess the main problem is something else.
Thanks for the reply though.