# Cannot play pcm > 60kb with the AndroidSimpleBufferQueue

Tags: android, opensl

I've initialized an AndroidSimpleBufferQueue such as values:

```
SLDataLocator_AndroidSimpleBufferQueue bufferLocator = {
  SL_DATALOCATOR_ANDROIDSIMPLEBUFFERQUEUE, 2};
SLDataFormat_PCM pcmFormat = {
  SL_DATAFORMAT_PCM,           1,
  SL_SAMPLINGRATE_44_1,        SL_PCMSAMPLEFORMAT_FIXED_16,
  SL_PCMSAMPLEFORMAT_FIXED_16, SL_SPEAKER_FRONT_CENTER,
  SL_BYTEORDER_LITTLEENDIAN};

SLDataSource            audioSource      = {&bufferLocator, &pcmFormat};
SLDataLocator_OutputMix locatorOutputMix = {SL_DATALOCATOR_OUTPUTMIX,
                                            outputMixObj.getObject()};
SLDataSink audioSink = {&locatorOutputMix, nullptr};
[...]
```

Then when I need to play a sound I enqueue such as:

```
bufferQueue->Enqueue(bufferQueue, (uint8_t*)buffer.data(),
          buffer.size())
```

It works well for buffer smaller than 60k however when the buffer is bigger no sound are played or sometime just an artifact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Specifications:

> The buffers that are queued are used in place and are not required to
>   be copied by the  device, although this may  be
>   implementation-dependent. The application developer  should be aware
>   that modifying the content  of a buffer after it has been queued is 
>   undefined and can cause audio corruption

So the **memory must remains valid** until the sound fully played.

*Read the documentation and be aware of unintended struct copy :)*